# Get first and 9th column values of a table using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a table with 10 columns and 20 rows. I need to print the column 1 and column 9 values for all rows

I have tried with

```
$("table tr").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).eq(0).text() + " " + $(this).eq(8).text())
});
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Columns are td elements not tr elements. You need to use `$(this).find('td').eq(0)` instead (note the additional `.find` chained in between.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Terry, As per your suggestion the below code works great

I am posting an answer myself, it may be helpful for some like me.

```
$("table tr").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).find("td").eq(1).text())
});
```